# Line Suppression State Error C4703 potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'back' used

Tags: c++

I am getting the error that I have a potentially uninitialized local pointer variable and I am not sure why.

```
Link *popBck(Link *list, int &val) {
        if (!list)return 0;

        Link *front = list, *back;
        while (front->ptr) {
            back = front;
            front = front->ptr;
        }
        val = front->data;
        delete front;
        back->ptr = 0;
        return list;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialise `back` here:

```
 Link *front = list, *back;
```

and the only assignment to `back` may not execute due to its being conditional:

```
while (front->ptr) {   // This condition could be false...
    back = front;      // ... in which case this doesn't happen.
    front = front->ptr;
}
```

which would cause you to dereference an uninitialised `back` here:

```
back->ptr = 0;
```

It is a good idea to always initialise variables.

You also need a special case for the singleton list, where you should return the null pointer.

If you initialise `back` to the null pointer, it will be null exactly when you have a list with only one element.

Something like this:

```
Link *popBack(Link *list, int &val) {
        if (!list) return nullptr;

        Link *front = list, *back = nullptr;
        while (front->ptr) {
            back = front;
            front = front->ptr;
        }
        val = front->data;
        delete front;

        if (!back)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
        else 
        {
            back->ptr = 0;
            return list;
        }
}
```